# What is 'cpoptions' += o?

Tags: set

What does `cpoptions` setting `'o'` does?

The doc [`:h cpo-o`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#cpo-o) reads

> Line offset to search command is not remembered for next search.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following text:

```
Test Case
First

Test Case
Second
```

and you search with `/Case/+1` from the beginning of the file. The cursor will end up on the text `First`. You searched for `Case` and gave the "line offset" +1. (See `:help search-offset`)

If cpoptions does **not** contain `o` and you press `n`, the cursor ends up on the text `Second`.

If cpoptions does contain `o` and you press `n` and the cursor ends up on the text `Case`. So the line offset was not remembered.

Comment: @elig Could you accept this answer or is additional clarification needed?